# Open a URL in Epiphany Web Browser from Python Script

Tags: python, pi-2

So I am trying to open a URL in Epiphany [ let's say for example `http://www.google.com` ] from a python script. My python script is as follows:

```
import os
string = "DISPLAY=:0 xdg-open http://www.google.com"
os.system(string)
```

It returns the error: `xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://www.google.com'`

However if I type `DISPLAY=:0 xdg-open http://www.google.com` into LXTerminal is works fine. It also works remotely through SSH.

Any Ideas? Also can someone explain to me why command were find in terminal, but not when you try to call them from a Python script?

**UPDATE -- NEED HELP STILL**

**NOTE:** All files are located in `/home/pi`

After much frustration, I figured I would give the below method a try. I created a file called `google.sh`. The code for `google.sh` s as follows:

```
#google.sh    
DISPLAY=:0 xdg-open http://www.google.com
```

when I call upon this program using `./google.sh` from LXTerminal it works fine! **Great** so now let's call it from a python script called `test.py` whose code is as follows:

```
# test.py
import os

string = "/home/pi/google.sh"
os.system(string)
```

However for some reason it STILL returns: `xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://www.google.com'`